# should I select columns before or after join?

Tags: mysql

I have a join that takes a lot of time:

`select t1.*, t.b from t1 join (select id, b from t2) t on t1.id = t.id`

I have an index on `id` in `t2`.

1. Is index on id preserved when I create a derived table t?
2. In terms of performance, do I need to select from t2, or would this be always as fast:

`select t1.*, t.b from t1 join t2 t on t1.id = t.id` ?

Comment: Why don't you use `select t1.*, t.b from t1 join t2 t on t1.id = t.id` always ?

Comment: I would if I was sure that keeping the other columns from t2 (which there can be many and I don't need them in the final result) will never make the query slower.

Comment: By the way `t` is not a temporary table. It's called **derived** table.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both formulations.

Comment: No, it doesn't make it slower, @Valentas. DBMSes are smart enough to know that if you only want one column that they will do their best to only read one column. Of course, if a full table scan is needed, you're going to be plowing through all of the data anyway.